# Check if player has passed an object

Tags: python, collision-detection

```
if ob1Count == 1 or ob1Count == 2 or ob1Count == 3:
        if q > 270 and q < 350:
            if yyy > 165:
                dead = True
            else:
                if q < 280:
                    points +=1
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(pointscore)
```

The game is an endless runner, where you have to jump over spikes. The first part of it is just my collision detection, the problem I am having is with the else: part (q is the X axis of the spike). After the player jumps over 10 spikes, the game speeds up, and for some reason it sometimes won't detect that the player has jumped over the spike and thus won't give them a point.

My question is, is there any better way to detect when a player has jumped over the spike rather than looking at the X axis? This method is very glitchy.

Also, another thing - shouldn't if q < 280 result in the player getting spammed with points until the spike disappears? Because it does not, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: no, they'd only get points from 271 onwards, because the first if would never trigger on 0->270

Comment: if it's faster, you could encounter a "tunnel effect": x is updated so fast that before update it is before the spike, and after update it has passed the spike, but is never actually _above_ the spike.

Comment: If you calculate the winning condition just before jump happens you could get results no matter the speed. What I am saying is that you can **predict** if a player will succeed just the moment he makes his move, because you have all the variables(speed, position, goal etc..) you need.

Comment: BTW, you can do `ob1Count in (1, 2, 3)` and `if 270 < q < 350`

Comment: Thanks @Rockybilly, that's the sort of thing I was looking for, it works well.